# How can I replace the right-most 30 pixels of my movie with black?

Tags: video, quicktime, video-editing, screen-recording

I'm using Mac OS 10.13.3.  I have Quicktime 10.4 installed if that will help here.  I recorded an application on my computer, however I recorded a little too much screen real estate.  I would like to remove, or barring that, black out, the right-most 30 pixels from my movie.  How can I do that on Mac using freeware tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a free video conversion tool available on Mac, Windows and Linux called [Handbrake](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwiimbWm7qjbAhWl5oMKHfQfA5cQFggvMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fhandbrake.fr%2F&usg=AOvVaw1RtQpdPWsD7StpHZYLnCO0). Handbrake does a lot of things, one of which is crop a video.

If you open a video and go to the picture tab you will get something that looks like this.

[image: Handbrake. Picture Tab]

At top right you have Cropping. Select custom and then adjust the number of pixels on each edge you want removed.